# Procedure pointer returned from a function with nagfor

Tags: pointers, fortran, procedure, fortran2003, nag-fortran

I try to use procedure pointers as a return of a function in Fortran. The following minimal code works with gfortran (tested with 4.8.1) but not with nagfor (NAG 6.0):

```
function foo() result(f_p)
  implicit none
  procedure(), pointer :: f_p
  f_p => null()
end function foo
```

nagfor complains with:

```
Error: test.f90, line 5: Multiply defined symbol F_P
   detected at ::@F_P
Error: test.f90, line 5: F_P is not a procedure name
   detected at F_P@<end-of-statement>
Warning: test.f90, line 7: Result F_P of function FOO has not been assigned a value
[NAG Fortran Compiler pass 1 error termination, 2 errors, 1 warning]
```

Why is this?

Note: I'm very well aware of the danger for memory leaks when using procedure pointers in this way.

Comment: I don't see any potential for memory leaks.

Comment: I would guess it is a still unimplemented feature from Fortran 2003 in this compiler, but let's wait for a while for more knowledgeable language lawyers.

Comment: well, yes, in the example above there is indeed no potential for memory leaks. ;-) thanks for your comment (also below).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I work on the NAG Fortran Compiler and I can confirm that it does not yet implement this Fortran 2003 feature (functions returning procedure pointers).
Support for the feature is tentatively scheduled for the next (6.1) release.

Comment: Now 6.1 is (long) released, can you confirm that this works?  [I could try myself, but if you're happy to...]

Comment: No, sorry. We have even deferred this beyond the current in-development 6.2.